# Import 2D matrix in 3D matrix using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

This function:

```
 filtro.kernel(n, mat)
```

returns a 2D matrix with 15x15 size, is there a way to add all 12 matrices that are calculated from the for cycle to a 3D matrix with size 12,15,15?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "filter.h"
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::zeros(15, 15, CV_32S);
    filter filtro;

    for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++){
        filtro.kernel(n, mat);
        cout<<"Angle Matrix"<<endl;
        cout<< n*15 <<endl;
        cout<< mat <<endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv::merge` to create a `multi-channels matrix`. But notice, the channels dimension is the last.`12 (15,15) => (15,15,12)`

Try this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "filter.h"
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    filter filtro;

    // Create a vector of Mat 
    vector<Mat> mats;

    for (int n = 0; n < 12; n++){  
        cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::zeros(15, 15, CV_32S);
        filtro.kernel(n, mat);
        cout<<"Angle Matrix"<<endl;
        cout<< n*15 <<endl;
        cout<< mat <<endl;   
        mats.push_back(mat);
    }

    // Merge the Mats
    Mat dst;
    merge(mats, dst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Do you know how could I individually access each one of the matrices and one element from one of the 12 matrices?

I tried to access one matrix this way:

    dst.at<int>(x)

but it only returns a value like 0, not the entire matrix.

Comment: @VeraCardoso You might be better off with just the `mats` vector rather than putting them into a 3D `cv::Mat`. Then you'd be able to use the syntax you suggest.